# python3 delete more than one elements in a list using another list as index

Tags: list, del

```
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(10).tolist()
n = [2, 6, 4]
```

I want to delete the 2nd, 6th, and 4th elements in list m.

```
del m[n]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

I tried this:

```
ns = np.sort(n)

for i in np.arange(len(ns)):
    m.pop(ns[i] - i)
```

but it pop out the deleted elements
Is there any elegant method to do this job?

Answer (score 1):

For this simple case, you can use `m = np.delete(m, n)`.

Here is a link to the doc : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much.